# Is there a way to force crash links opened as new tabs in firefox?

Tags: redirect, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to open up a whole bunch of links that would fill up RAM and slow things down to work through them one at a time.

I know in theory I could add the links one at a time to list in an add-on or another program, but I really like having my workflow as tabs that are grouped into one window and if I have to compare two tabs I can open them up easily as they are all right there and force crash as I go if I need to.

I was thinking one way of accomplishing this might be to get all links that are opened on as new tabs could be redirected to "about:tabcrashed" after opening the link, but I am not sure how to go about that.